# How to obtain Android native StackView from Xamarin.Forms.StackLayout?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I need to obtain the native Android StackView control from Xamarin.Forms.StackLayout instance. Here is some pseudo-code to explain the problem:

```
 void ProcessMySL(Xamarin.Forms.StackLayout sl) {
   var renderer =
    Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.RendererFactory.GetRenderer(sl);
   ...
 }
```

When I examine renderer object, it is of type `Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.VisualElementRenderer`. However, it does not have any property such as `Control` to get me the native `StackView` object.

I am wondering how can I obtain the native view. Regards.

Comment: This looks like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) in the making. What's your reasoning for needing the renderer and why doesn't building a custom renderer work?

Comment: Thank you for your help. I need to set ContentDescription field on the native Android StackView.

Comment: Why doesn't building a custom renderer work?

Comment: I have being doing it successfully for other controls such as Buttons without resorting to custom renderers. I am thinking why should this control be any different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears `Xamarin.Forms.StackLayout` in not rendered as Android's `StackView` control but a more generic `ViewGroup` object. To get the Android native view, the following code would work:

```
var renderer = RenderFactory.GetRenderer(stackLayout);
Android.Views.View view = renderer.ViewGroup;
...
```

Answer (score 0):

> Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.VisualElementRenderer. However, it does not have any property such as Control to get me the native StackView object.

Refering to the official document of Renderer:[Renderer Base Classes and Native Control](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/custom-renderer/renderers/). `StackLayout` is using `ViewRenderer` and is thus rendered into a `View` object, not a `StackView`.

Besides, using `Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.RendererFactory.GetRenderer(sl)` only return a `DefaultRenderer`, which doesn't expose the `Control` property. So, please create a custom renderer instead.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Your hint about using ViewRenderer worked for me. Regards.